# Can a user avoid a question ban by deleting and opening a new account?

Tags: discussion, post-ban

I'm asking this because I suspect a user is doing this and it caused me to lose rep because they upvoted my answers on their questions. That user asked perhaps too many questions, which are sometimes closed or downvoted, and told me in chat that they can't ask more. Then their account was [deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12904074)  (link included FYI mods), but reappeared today with the same name and 101 rep (because they have an account on another community, which was not deleted), again asking questions of mediocre quality.

So I'm just wondering if this 'trick' can actually get around the question ban? If so, is there anything we can do to discourage this behaviour?

Also does the question ban criteria depend on the rep of the user (1 vs 101), or just the quality of the questions they asked?

Comment: thanks, it partially does for my first question, but not my second question @JeanneDark

Comment: Even if a user does avoid it and you still suspect something fishy, flag for a mod. They have the tools to verify your gut feeling.

Comment: The quality-ban algorithm only takes score of all posts into account.

Comment: Thanks @rene , will close the question as dupe then

Comment: Specifically, you need to raise a "in need of moderator intervention" flag pointing out the user account that you suspect of sockpuppetry and all other evidence that you might be able to provide. Closing the question is good, but doesn't bring the sockpuppetry to moderator attention.